# Xcode 6 Auto layout only iphone 4

Tags: autolayout, ios8, constraints, xcode6

how to work with auto layout classes in one phone only
for example I want to make distance between screen top edge and the element 50 px in iphone 4 but in iPhone 5 i want to make it 100 px

i need to but distance for each device separately

Comment: Modify the constraints' constant values in code. But why would you need to set different values for each device? Set up your hierarchy like so, that constraints are relative and let the system do the work.

Comment: Because the elements in the iPhone 4 show off the screen 
show larger unlike the iPhone 6 Plus 
I want to minimize the elements in small screens and large them in big screens like iPhone 6 Plus